# how to show dir of file in new page for type=file tags?

Tags: php

i write my news in registernews.php and in newsedit.php edit them, when select one of them in listnews.php in newsedit.php showed information of this news for example title , keyword etc, but when i want show url of image and file that belong this file in edit mode, i can't do it.
i have type=file in both form but want write in newsedit same below.

```
<input name="nimg"  type="file" value="<?php echo $nimg1 ?>" >
```

That $nimg1 saved for news that want edit.
ofter run newsedit.php , "no file selected" showed for input tag that type is file

Comment: Do you just have the filename stored in the database or a path?

Comment: I saved path of file in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input file means: what file from the client side do you want to upload.

Let's take an example: 
1) I am your user. I have on my desktop an image called "to_upload.jpg". I go to **newsedit.php** and upload my news + my image from desktop => the image will be uploaded on the server. After that, I delete my image from the desktop.
2) Some weeks afer I want to edit that news (maybe only the title).

What's wrong? You try to link a file which doesn't exist on client's disk. Even if ou do that, the HTML does NOT parse to the server, the client path (eg.: C:\users..).

Your solution may be something like this:

On newsedit.php:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="uploads_dir/<?php echo $file_name; ?>"></td>
        <td>Uplaod new image: <input name="nimg"  type="file"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The idea is simple: display the current image (uploaded image), and an input file if the user want to change the image of the news.